# xslt: joining arbitrary number of xml files into a single xml

Tags: xml, xslt, join

I have the following xsl script, which can join two xml files into one file by a field:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="trans" match="Transaction" use="id" />

  <!-- Identity template to copy everything we don't specifically override -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- override for Mail elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Mail">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy all children as normal -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:variable name="myId" select="id" />
      <Transaction_data>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('transactions.xml')">
          <!-- process all transactions with the right ID -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans', $myId)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Transaction_data>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- omit the id element when copying a Transaction -->
  <xsl:template match="Transaction/id" />
```

I'd like to perform the same process with arbitrary number of xml files by the same join node. Is it possible somehow in a single xsl file?

Comment: How are the file names specified?  In the input XML file, via a parameter, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the file names are given from outside via parameters. So, we can assume, that file2, file3, ... filen will contain the path of the remaining xml files.

Comment: Yes, just provide the argument to `document()` as a nodeset, each node containing the URI of a document.

Comment: Please, provide the exact XML for three documents so that we can give you the solution. Without exact XML documents this isn't meaningful.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049561) is the previous question, to which the above XSLT was [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13050102/592139).

Comment: @IanRoberts, It is the responsibility of the asker to provide all information -- not to create a chain of related information, residing in different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process an arbitrary number of input files then consider to pass an XML document with the file names as a parameter e.g. pass as a parameter a file `files-to-process` with contents alike

```
<files>
  <file>foo.xml</file>
  <file>bar.xml</file>
  <file>baz.xml</file>
</files>
```

then have

```
<xsl:param name="files-url" select="'files-to-process.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="files-doc" select="document($files-url)"/>
```

and then simply change

```
  <xsl:template match="Mail">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy all children as normal -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:variable name="myId" select="id" />
      <Transaction_data>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('transactions.xml')">
          <!-- process all transactions with the right ID -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans', $myId)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Transaction_data>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="Mail">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy all children as normal -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:variable name="myId" select="id" />
      <Transaction_data>
        <xsl:for-each select="document($files-doc/files/file)">
          <!-- process all transactions with the right ID -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans', $myId)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Transaction_data>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

That way you can process all files named in `files/file` in the document passed in as a parameter.